# How do i gain access to subproccess.py?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

So, my bot for some reason wants to access a folder in `\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\Lib` called `subproccess.py` but it always gives the error: `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`. I think it has to do with ffmpeg.

Here's the full traceback (kinda long):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\interactions\client\client.py", line 1900, in __dispatch_interaction
    response = await callback
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\interactions\client\client.py", line 1771, in _run_slash_command
    return await command(ctx, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\command.py", line 132, in __call__
    await self.call_callback(self.callback, context)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\application_commands.py", line 802, in call_callback
    return await self.call_with_binding(callback, ctx)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\callback.py", line 43, in call_with_binding
    return await callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop\button.py", line 38, in press
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=r"C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop\ffmpeg-6.1-essentials_build\bin", source=audiosource))
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.Bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 290, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 166, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 180, in _spawn_process
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.bunch_of_numbers\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

heres my code:

```
import interactions
import discord
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import tracemalloc

ffmpegexec = r"C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop\ffmpeg-6.1-essentials_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

audiosource = r"C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\seatbelt-online-audio-converter.mp3"

source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audiosource)

token = "my_token"

bot = interactions.Client(token=token)

tracemalloc.start()

@interactions.slash_command(
    name="joinvc",
    description="starts the game"
)

async def joinvc(ctx: interactions.ComponentContext):
    await ctx.send("Joining vc. Please make sure you are currently in a vc!")
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await vc.connect()

@interactions.slash_command(
    name="press",
    description="Press the button"
)

async def press(ctx: interactions.ComponentContext):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has pressed the button")
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await vc.connect()  # Connect to the voice channel

voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=r"C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive\Desktop\ffmpeg-6.1-essentials_build\bin", source=audiosource))


bot.start(token)
```

All of my code is above. I'm not exactly good at writing python, might just be something I'm misunderstanding. I just want it to play a noise in a discord voice chat when the /press command is used.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your Python code -- it's a question of the security products on your system and what rules they're applying. (Windows Store apps also have their own sandboxing, which is why installing software _without_ going through the Windows Store gives you more flexibility, presuming of course that it's something you trust).

Comment: (You might think of using a different audio library, one that interfaces directly with the win32 API and _doesn't_ require starting a separate program like ffmpeg; as long as what you're playing is small/short enough to be saved as WAV without using an unreasonable amount of space, that's probably the quickest/easiest class of fix)

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not exactly sure what is going on. But it seems some of your Python packages are installed in Program Files and your Python script cannot access it (that part is normal).

In general I suggest using a virtual environment, in which you have full control over the Python version and included packages in the specific environment. Also, all package data is then stored together with your Python files.
The only issues you might then run into is if data you need is stored in OneDrive (which usually gives me that same access error).

This is for example the path where subprocess.py is stored for me in my current project:

```
"C:\Workspaces\x\x\x\.conda\Lib\subprocess.py"
```

Normally I store data, code and .conda virtual environment in the same Workspace folder.

Comment: The problem is during a CreateProcess call (akin to fork/exec on UNIX), not while trying to load Python packages or code. As far as I can tell, this answer isn't on-point for the question at all.

Comment: Likely because CreateProcess is (also) in Program Files/WindowsApps. Which would in fact be fixed with Python in a virtual environment. To minimize PermissionErrors, my recommendation still stands.

Comment: CreateProcess is a syscall, not a library; it's being invoked from the standard library of the Python interpreter located in WindowsApps -- if the Python interpreter (itself installed from the app store) couldn't read files _from the same app store entry as that interpreter itself_ it wouldn't have been able to start up at all; moreover, the import of `subprocess.py` would have failed, so we never would have reached the point of trying to execute code within that file.

Comment: To be clear, you're wandering in the general neighborhood of something I'd consider a credible answer -- the Windows Store sandbox is a likely component of the problem to be sure -- but wandering near a correct answer is not providing a correct answer; not just the proposed solution but the explanation of why that solution helps should also be correct.

Comment: if "C:\Workspaces\x\x\x\.conda\Lib\subprocess.py" is meant to be the string representation of your path, you should either consider adding a r prefix before the first " (meaning it's a raw string where backslashes are not interpreted, duplicate the backslashes or use / instead, because in that form you could get unwanted results in case a character follows a backslash that forms a known escape sequence like \n or \r.